# Can I use RDS format to protect my script's code

Tags: r, save

I would like to protect my script code from being read or reverse engineered.If I call my script from another R file using the `source` function, will the code that is stored in RDS format remain protected or Is there any way to read it like a usual r code?

Comment: Don't you think that is contradictory to the whole spirit of *open source*? Imo, much like you profit from all guys in this community, it might be nice, if others can learn from your code.

Comment: @loki the spirit of open source is that you can do anything, including try and hide your code if you want (as long as you don't break the license by distributing anything in contraventions to the GPL or other license).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be read trivially. Just read it in using something like:

```
code = readRDS("mysecretcode.rds")
```

and everything is in `code`.

If you want someone to run your R code then at some point it has to be de-obfuscated or de-crypted so the R interpreter can understand it. An attacker can get the code at that point.

If you really don't want anyone to see your code, keep it on a server and only let people call it via a network API.

Comment: Thank you @Spaceman, do you have any recommended source to learn about network API with R?